# Custom template for specific node in Drupal 6?

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-6

I know there are a ton of different custom template files like page.tpl.php and node.tpl.php etc. But is there a way to make a custom template for a specific node ID? This doesn't work node-3.tpl.php, but is there a way to accomplish this?

UPDATE CODE

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    $vars['template_files'][] = 'node-' . $vars['nid'];
}
```

Comment: @Enrich
I need the same thing, I tried what you have mentioned here but it didn't rendered for me.  If I am not wrong, I need to append this function in template.php?

Answer (score 4):

For Drupal 6, the page template is 'page-node-3.tpl.php' and read the manual at http://drupal.org/node/1089642

Drupal 7, page--node--3.tpl.php : http://drupal.org/node/1089656

Thanks @Clive and @asiby.

Comment: That's for Drupal 7. Drupal 6 manual is here: http://drupal.org/node/1089642, the right template file is `page-node-3.tpl.php`

Comment: I tried that first and yes that does work, but that's for the entire page. So I would have to duplicate my page template. So now if I needed to make an adjustment to my page template I would have to remember to do it in both or x amount of places for however many custom node templates I made. I wanted to only customize the node display for the given node as opposed to the entire page.

Comment: @ErichH. If you're overriding a node template you need a copy of the core `node.tpl.php` file in your theme as well. If you haven't already, copy that over, clear the cache, and you should be good to go

Comment: I did some searching on the topic and found out that in Drupal 6 out of the box, node-3.tpl.php will not work. It looked like it was treating it the same as page-node-3.tpl.php which again is not what I want as that is the entire template. So I found some code that will add the specified template pattern to "nodes" and I got it to work.If you add the code found in my update to my original post
to a custom module, you can now use "node-3.tpl.php and it will be for the node content itself and not the entire page.

Comment: @ErichH. What I wrote above is from page templates. node templates goes inside of page templates (i.e page is the base, and node is the content area)

Comment: @AyeshK, I need the same thing,I tried what Enrich have updated function but it didn't rendered for me. If I am not wrong, I need to append this function in template.php?

Comment: @AyeshK, I am also using Drupal 6

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you rebuild the theme registry. Failure to do so will result in Drupal completely ignoring the **node-x.tpl.php** file that you will add.