# How to add different template for different nodes in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I have 3 nodes in my sites.

1. node/1 - Login
2. node/2 - Contact
3. node/3 - Register

I want to have different template for different nodes. If I do as *page-node-1.tpl.php , page-node-2-tpl.php , its for the entire page, I don't want that*, I want specifically override for node content.

I have already tried the following links:-

- [Custom template for specific node in Drupal 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870349/custom-template-for-specific-node-in-drupal-6)
- [Using different templates for different nodes in Drupal 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190531/using-different-templates-for-different-nodes-in-drupal-7)

**I am using Drupal 6**

Comment: Ayesh is right. Just don't forget to clear the cache after you add new template file!

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Drupal 6 in a while, but from what I realized, Drupal 6's default node templates will not have a node ID based template suggestion.

That does not mean you cannot do it from a custom theme.

```
<?php

function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    $vars['template_files'][] = 'node-' . $vars['nid'];
}

?>
```

In your theme's template.php, add the above code, replacing the theme name (or merge the function contents if you already have that function). This will make the Drupal check for `node-123.tpl.php` file (`123` being an example node ID), and will use it for in place of `node.tpl.php`.

Since you mentioned you'd be using `node/1` or any node contents to embed a login form, let me tell you that this isn't exactly a good idea. The login form needs to be accessible when the site is in maintenance mode, and it can be hard to manage them later with different deployment environments. This part is completely irrelevant to the question though.

Comment: It was a PHP code and I had forgotten to use proper markup for that. Fixed now.

Comment: theme name is 100bags, if I try to put this theme name in the function, I gets an error. I should put this function in template.php right?

Comment: this name is chosen by some other dev prior to me

Comment: In the template.php file, yes. `100bags` is an unfortunate name for the theme because PHP function names should start with A-Z or `_`. You will have to rename the theme machine name (rename the theme .info file).

Comment: Yes I did.error goes off but still didn't pick the node-3.tpl.php

Comment: By the way,for your info 
I am trying to override the webform template